# Is this function $L^1(]0,1])$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory

### Background:

I was asking myself if in order to prove that given two random variables $X,Y \in L^1$ (i.e. with finite mean value) then $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$. I was asking myself if we can avoid to require $\mathbb{E}[|XY|]<+\infty$.

**I tried in this way:**

Define $\mathscr{Q}=]0,1] \times ]0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Define $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$ for $(x,y) \in \mathscr{Q}$.

**My problem:**

How can I compute $\int_{\mathscr{Q}}f(x,y) d\mu$ where $\mu$ denote the Lebesgue measure of $\mathscr{Q}$?

I think that $\int_{\mathscr{Q}}f(x,y) d\mu=+\infty$ but I cannot understand if it is true and I do not manage to proof correctly why.

Comment: Just try to compute the iterated integrals. What do you get?

Comment: the answer to your additional question is no unless your random variables are independent. Your example is one in which the random variables are independent.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thus we cannot avoid to require $\mathbb{E}[|XY|]<+\infty$? In the answer I understood my example is unuseful. Do you have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular example, $f\in L_1$. Use Fubini's theorem

$$
\int_\mathscr{Q} f=\int^1_0\Big(\int^1_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}\,dx\Big)\,dy=\Big(\int^1_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\,dy\Big)\Big(\int^1_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\Big)
$$

As for the added question, the answer is no in general but for sure if your random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Example, take the probability space $(\mathscr{Q},\mathscr{B}),\mu)$ that you defined ($\mathscr{Q}=[0,1]^2$), $\mu$ Lebesgue measure on the plane. Define $X(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=Y(x,y)$ Then $X$ and $Y$ are integrable, by clearly $XY$ is not integrable and so $E[XY]\neq E[X]E[Y]$.

Comment: Actually my problem was in the first sentence, could you please add more details? I am sorry if I modified it later.